Replicate an existing google form into google slides
I am trying to copy the image and function of a created google form and insert it into google slides. I want students to be able to click on multiple choice answers on their Chrome books as they follow along with the presentation instead of having to click on a link.
Coppy HTML and paste, use third party software but it came with a fee.
